# G1GC - Allocation Failure alongside Humongous Allocation

Tags: java, java-8, garbage-collection

Since a while, tuning up JVM GC parameters to avoid slowness and UI down.
It recently reach a moment, that facing [Allocation Failure].

openjdk 1.8.6_166

```
 6934.438: [G1Ergonomics (Concurrent Cycles) do not request concurrent cycle initiation, reason: still doing mixed collections, occupancy: 17213423616 bytes, allocation request: 65011736 bytes, threshold: 13743895320 bytes (40.00 %), source: concurrent humongous allocation]
2022-06-07T07:57:53.690+0000: 6934.450: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0118833 seconds, Stopping threads took: 0.0023018 seconds
 6934.533: [G1Ergonomics (Concurrent Cycles) do not request concurrent cycle initiation, reason: still doing mixed collections, occupancy: 17280532480 bytes, allocation request: 65011736 bytes, threshold: 13743895320 bytes (40.00 %), source: concurrent humongous allocation]
 6934.582: [G1Ergonomics (Concurrent Cycles) do not request concurrent cycle initiation, reason: still doing mixed collections, occupancy: 17347641344 bytes, allocation request: 130023480 bytes, threshold: 13743895320 bytes (40.00 %), source: concurrent humongous allocation]
2022-06-07T07:57:53.833+0000: 6934.593: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0379460 seconds, Stopping threads took: 0.0283039 seconds
 6934.846: [G1Ergonomics (Concurrent Cycles) do not request concurrent cycle initiation, reason: still doing mixed collections, occupancy: 17481859072 bytes, allocation request: 130023480 bytes, threshold: 13743895320 bytes (40.00 %), source: concurrent humongous allocation]
2022-06-07T07:57:54.279+0000: 6935.039: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0140351 seconds, Stopping threads took: 0.0041265 seconds
2022-06-07T07:57:54.329+0000: 6935.088: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0245153 seconds, Stopping threads took: 0.0043713 seconds
2022-06-07T07:57:54.338+0000: 6935.098: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0089223 seconds, Stopping threads took: 0.0004806 seconds
2022-06-07T07:57:54.358+0000: 6935.118: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0143016 seconds, Stopping threads took: 0.0037498 seconds
2022-06-07T07:57:54.367+0000: 6935.127: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0085460 seconds, Stopping threads took: 0.0003827 seconds
2022-06-07T07:57:54.384+0000: 6935.144: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0135096 seconds, Stopping threads took: 0.0007653 seconds
2022-06-07T07:57:54.643+0000: 6935.402: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0330644 seconds, Stopping threads took: 0.0058025 seconds
{Heap before GC invocations=1697 (full 20):
 garbage-first heap   total 33554432K, used 30424749K [0x00007f0bd4000000, 0x00007f0bd5004000, 0x00007f13d4000000)
  region size 16384K, 819 young (13418496K), 77 survivors (1261568K)
 Metaspace       used 552838K, capacity 598489K, committed 624640K, reserved 624640K
2022-06-07T07:57:54.955+0000: 6935.714: [GC pause (G1 Evacuation Pause) (young)
Desired survivor size 864026624 bytes, new threshold 15 (max 15)
- age   1:  100659160 bytes,  100659160 total
- age   2:   56388016 bytes,  157047176 total
- age   3:   46964376 bytes,  204011552 total
- age   4:   22241848 bytes,  226253400 total
- age   5:   21002752 bytes,  247256152 total
- age   6:    2069056 bytes,  249325208 total
- age   7:   18551720 bytes,  267876928 total
- age   8:   21299392 bytes,  289176320 total
- age   9:   18800528 bytes,  307976848 total
- age  10:   13761672 bytes,  321738520 total
- age  11:   22935312 bytes,  344673832 total
- age  12:     912328 bytes,  345586160 total
- age  13:   18947448 bytes,  364533608 total
- age  14:   16714912 bytes,  381248520 total
- age  15:    2604776 bytes,  383853296 total
 6935.718: [G1Ergonomics (CSet Construction) start choosing CSet, _pending_cards: 321900, predicted base time: 306.94 ms, remaining time: 0.00 ms, target pause time: 100.00 ms]
 6935.718: [G1Ergonomics (CSet Construction) add young regions to CSet, eden: 742 regions, survivors: 77 regions, predicted young region time: 136.39 ms]
 6935.718: [G1Ergonomics (CSet Construction) finish choosing CSet, eden: 742 regions, survivors: 77 regions, old: 0 regions, predicted pause time: 443.33 ms, target pause time: 100.00 ms]
2022-06-07T07:57:55.080+0000: 6935.840: [SoftReference, 0 refs, 0.0115803 secs]2022-06-07T07:57:55.091+0000: 6935.851: [WeakReference, 20134 refs, 0.0048803 secs]2022-06-07T07:57:55.096+0000: 6935.856: [FinalReference, 1251 refs, 0.0059053 secs]2022-06-07T07:57:55.102+0000: 6935.862: [PhantomReference, 150 refs, 73 refs, 0.0170622 secs]2022-06-07T07:57:55.119+0000: 6935.879: [JNI Weak Reference, 0.0002034 secs] 6935.909: [G1Ergonomics (Concurrent Cycles) do not request concurrent cycle initiation, reason: still doing mixed collections, occupancy: 17112760320 bytes, allocation request: 0 bytes, threshold: 13743895320 bytes (40.00 %), source: end of GC]
 6935.909: [G1Ergonomics (Mixed GCs) do not start mixed GCs, reason: reclaimable percentage not over threshold, candidate old regions: 130 regions, reclaimable: 1018251912 bytes (2.96 %), threshold: 5.00 %]
, 0.1951290 secs]
   [Parallel Time: 117.9 ms, GC Workers: 40]
      [GC Worker Start (ms): Min: 6935718.9, Avg: 6935722.7, Max: 6935727.2, Diff: 8.2]
      [Ext Root Scanning (ms): Min: 0.1, Avg: 5.1, Max: 108.6, Diff: 108.5, Sum: 203.0]
      [Update RS (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 44.1, Max: 47.5, Diff: 47.5, Sum: 1763.1]
         [Processed Buffers: Min: 0, Avg: 40.3, Max: 61, Diff: 61, Sum: 1613]
      [Scan RS (ms): Min: 0.1, Avg: 2.9, Max: 3.3, Diff: 3.2, Sum: 116.9]
      [Code Root Scanning (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 0.0, Max: 0.1, Diff: 0.1, Sum: 0.2]
      [Object Copy (ms): Min: 6.3, Avg: 60.4, Max: 62.1, Diff: 55.8, Sum: 2417.0]
      [Termination (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 0.0, Max: 0.1, Diff: 0.1, Sum: 0.8]
         [Termination Attempts: Min: 1, Avg: 1.0, Max: 1, Diff: 0, Sum: 40]
      [GC Worker Other (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 0.5, Max: 1.0, Diff: 1.0, Sum: 19.0]
      [GC Worker Total (ms): Min: 108.2, Avg: 113.0, Max: 117.2, Diff: 9.0, Sum: 4519.9]
      [GC Worker End (ms): Min: 6935835.3, Avg: 6935835.7, Max: 6935836.3, Diff: 1.0]
   [Code Root Fixup: 0.2 ms]
   [Code Root Purge: 0.0 ms]
   [String Dedup Fixup: 17.3 ms, GC Workers: 40]
      [Queue Fixup (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 0.0, Max: 0.1, Diff: 0.1, Sum: 0.4]
      [Table Fixup (ms): Min: 12.9, Avg: 13.8, Max: 14.2, Diff: 1.3, Sum: 550.4]
   [Clear CT: 2.4 ms]
   [Other: 57.3 ms]
      [Choose CSet: 0.0 ms]
      [Ref Proc: 42.3 ms]
      [Ref Enq: 2.9 ms]
      [Redirty Cards: 3.5 ms]
      [Humongous Register: 0.2 ms]
      [Humongous Reclaim: 0.5 ms]
      [Free CSet: 2.7 ms]
   [Eden: 11.6G(11.6G)->0.0B(11.8G) Survivors: 1232.0M->1008.0M Heap: 29.0G(32.0G)->16.8G(32.0G)]
Heap after GC invocations=1698 (full 20):
 garbage-first heap   total 33554432K, used 17566138K [0x00007f0bd4000000, 0x00007f0bd5004000, 0x00007f13d4000000)
  region size 16384K, 63 young (1032192K), 63 survivors (1032192K)
 Metaspace       used 552838K, capacity 598489K, committed 624640K, reserved 624640K
}
 [Times: user=5.40 sys=0.00, real=0.20 secs] 
2022-06-07T07:57:55.151+0000: 6935.911: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.2108179 seconds, Stopping threads took: 0.0049857 seconds
2022-06-07T07:57:55.178+0000: 6935.938: [GC concurrent-string-deduplication, 6529.0K->2055.8K(4473.2K), avg 52.3%, 0.0265075 secs]
2022-06-07T07:57:55.680+0000: 6936.440: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0124845 seconds, Stopping threads took: 0.0028985 seconds
2022-06-07T07:57:56.215+0000: 6936.975: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0115488 seconds, Stopping threads took: 0.0023418 seconds
2022-06-07T07:57:57.265+0000: 6938.025: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0413407 seconds, Stopping threads took: 0.0320317 seconds
2022-06-07T07:57:57.275+0000: 6938.035: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0097738 seconds, Stopping threads took: 0.0020407 seconds
 6938.094: [G1Ergonomics (Concurrent Cycles) request concurrent cycle initiation, reason: occupancy higher than threshold, occupancy: 17112760320 bytes, allocation request: 8388632 bytes, threshold: 13743895320 bytes (40.00 %), source: concurrent humongous allocation]
 6938.115: [G1Ergonomics (Concurrent Cycles) request concurrent cycle initiation, reason: requested by GC cause, GC cause: G1 Humongous Allocation]
{Heap before GC invocations=1698 (full 20):
 garbage-first heap   total 33554432K, used 24627642K [0x00007f0bd4000000, 0x00007f0bd5004000, 0x00007f13d4000000)
  region size 16384K, 495 young (8110080K), 63 survivors (1032192K)
 Metaspace       used 553004K, capacity 598749K, committed 624640K, reserved 624640K
 6938.115: [G1Ergonomics (Concurrent Cycles) initiate concurrent cycle, reason: concurrent cycle initiation requested]
2022-06-07T07:57:57.355+0000: 6938.115: [GC pause (G1 Humongous Allocation) (young) (initial-mark)
Desired survivor size 864026624 bytes, new threshold 15 (max 15)
- age   1:  132312664 bytes,  132312664 total
- age   2:   53174384 bytes,  185487048 total
- age   3:   46033920 bytes,  231520968 total
- age   4:   36081520 bytes,  267602488 total
- age   5:   21620992 bytes,  289223480 total
- age   6:   20199304 bytes,  309422784 total
- age   7:    2053112 bytes,  311475896 total
- age   8:   18422848 bytes,  329898744 total
- age   9:   21208568 bytes,  351107312 total
- age  10:   18671480 bytes,  369778792 total
- age  11:   13736560 bytes,  383515352 total
- age  12:   22850056 bytes,  406365408 total
- age  13:     908232 bytes,  407273640 total
- age  14:   17499712 bytes,  424773352 total
- age  15:   16658968 bytes,  441432320 total
 6938.116: [G1Ergonomics (CSet Construction) start choosing CSet, _pending_cards: 66608, predicted base time: 227.63 ms, remaining time: 0.00 ms, target pause time: 100.00 ms]
 6938.116: [G1Ergonomics (CSet Construction) add young regions to CSet, eden: 432 regions, survivors: 63 regions, predicted young region time: 108.23 ms]
 6938.116: [G1Ergonomics (CSet Construction) finish choosing CSet, eden: 432 regions, survivors: 63 regions, old: 0 regions, predicted pause time: 335.86 ms, target pause time: 100.00 ms]
2022-06-07T07:57:57.492+0000: 6938.252: [SoftReference, 0 refs, 0.0140203 secs]2022-06-07T07:57:57.506+0000: 6938.266: [WeakReference, 20602 refs, 0.0557941 secs]2022-06-07T07:57:57.562+0000: 6938.321: [FinalReference, 468 refs, 0.0194280 secs]2022-06-07T07:57:57.581+0000: 6938.341: [PhantomReference, 119 refs, 73 refs, 0.0214794 secs]2022-06-07T07:57:57.603+0000: 6938.362: [JNI Weak Reference, 0.0002313 secs], 0.2956743 secs]
   [Parallel Time: 122.9 ms, GC Workers: 40]
      [GC Worker Start (ms): Min: 6938130.6, Avg: 6938131.8, Max: 6938133.1, Diff: 2.5]
      [Ext Root Scanning (ms): Min: 44.8, Avg: 47.7, Max: 108.1, Diff: 63.3, Sum: 1909.4]
      [Update RS (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 9.9, Max: 10.9, Diff: 10.9, Sum: 397.1]
         [Processed Buffers: Min: 0, Avg: 13.1, Max: 22, Diff: 22, Sum: 523]
      [Scan RS (ms): Min: 0.1, Avg: 2.9, Max: 3.3, Diff: 3.3, Sum: 117.0]
      [Code Root Scanning (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 0.0, Max: 0.1, Diff: 0.1, Sum: 0.1]
      [Object Copy (ms): Min: 0.7, Avg: 28.1, Max: 29.9, Diff: 29.2, Sum: 1124.1]
      [Termination (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 19.5, Max: 20.2, Diff: 20.2, Sum: 780.5]
         [Termination Attempts: Min: 1, Avg: 2.1, Max: 3, Diff: 2, Sum: 85]
      [GC Worker Other (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 0.5, Max: 1.2, Diff: 1.2, Sum: 21.6]
      [GC Worker Total (ms): Min: 106.9, Avg: 108.7, Max: 110.2, Diff: 3.2, Sum: 4349.8]
      [GC Worker End (ms): Min: 6938240.0, Avg: 6938240.5, Max: 6938241.2, Diff: 1.2]
   [Code Root Fixup: 0.2 ms]
   [Code Root Purge: 0.0 ms]
   [String Dedup Fixup: 16.4 ms, GC Workers: 40]
      [Queue Fixup (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 0.0, Max: 0.1, Diff: 0.1, Sum: 0.3]
      [Table Fixup (ms): Min: 6.7, Avg: 12.5, Max: 15.1, Diff: 8.4, Sum: 501.8]
   [Clear CT: 3.7 ms]
   [Other: 152.4 ms]
      [Choose CSet: 0.0 ms]
      [Ref Proc: 120.3 ms]
      [Ref Enq: 21.5 ms]
      [Redirty Cards: 3.4 ms]
      [Humongous Register: 0.1 ms]
      [Humongous Reclaim: 0.1 ms]
      [Free CSet: 1.7 ms]
   [Eden: 6912.0M(11.8G)->0.0B(11.9G) Survivors: 1008.0M->944.0M Heap: 23.5G(32.0G)->16.7G(32.0G)]
Heap after GC invocations=1699 (full 20):
 garbage-first heap   total 33554432K, used 17499403K [0x00007f0bd4000000, 0x00007f0bd5004000, 0x00007f13d4000000)
  region size 16384K, 59 young (966656K), 59 survivors (966656K)
 Metaspace       used 553004K, capacity 598749K, committed 624640K, reserved 624640K
}
 [Times: user=6.09 sys=0.00, real=0.30 secs] 
2022-06-07T07:57:57.651+0000: 6938.411: [GC concurrent-root-region-scan-start]
2022-06-07T07:57:57.652+0000: 6938.412: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.3098996 seconds, Stopping threads took: 0.0041009 seconds
2022-06-07T07:57:57.673+0000: 6938.432: [GC concurrent-string-deduplication, 4572.4K->1162.4K(3410.0K), avg 52.3%, 0.0202856 secs]
2022-06-07T07:57:57.752+0000: 6938.512: [GC concurrent-root-region-scan-end, 0.1006230 secs]
2022-06-07T07:57:57.752+0000: 6938.512: [GC concurrent-mark-start]
2022-06-07T07:57:57.793+0000: 6938.553: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0434723 seconds, Stopping threads took: 0.0348861 seconds
2022-06-07T07:57:58.283+0000: 6939.042: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0400358 seconds, Stopping threads took: 0.0313795 seconds
2022-06-07T07:57:58.369+0000: 6939.129: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0402108 seconds, Stopping threads took: 0.0314033 seconds
2022-06-07T07:57:58.987+0000: 6939.747: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.1185393 seconds, Stopping threads took: 0.1098118 seconds
2022-06-07T07:57:59.743+0000: 6940.503: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0739787 seconds, Stopping threads took: 0.0338976 seconds
2022-06-07T07:57:59.893+0000: 6940.653: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0475812 seconds, Stopping threads took: 0.0391463 seconds
2022-06-07T07:58:00.716+0000: 6941.476: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0827453 seconds, Stopping threads took: 0.0675092 seconds
2022-06-07T07:58:00.883+0000: 6941.643: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.1643206 seconds, Stopping threads took: 0.1555807 seconds
2022-06-07T07:58:01.185+0000: 6941.945: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0777454 seconds, Stopping threads took: 0.0687163 seconds
2022-06-07T07:58:01.222+0000: 6941.982: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0268858
```

Below, I am using that particular settings for JVM GC to handle the stuff. I am really, thinking that allocation of the object in the Region - Young Eden is too much, getting 12 GB, so perhaps cutting down object size + limitating HeapRegionSize will help out. RegionSize being on 40% of heap (outstanding value) is not dealing with concurrent cycles, isn't it ? That is going over the threshold.
Thinking about :
**-XX:G1HeapRegionSize=16M
-XX:G1NewSizePercent=10**

```
JAVA_OPTIONS="
    -DSoftKillWaitSeconds=0 
    -Djava.awt.headless=true 
    -Djenkins.install.runSetupWizard=false  
    -DoctaneAllowedStorage=/apps/x/ 
    -Djava.io.tmpdir=/x/bin/temp 
    -Dhudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP=\"\" 
    -Xms32g -Xmx32g -Xss1m -server 
    -XX:+UseG1GC 
    -XX:+ExplicitGCInvokesConcurrent 
    -XX:+ParallelRefProcEnabled 
    -XX:+UseStringDeduplication
    -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions 
    -XX:G1NewSizePercent=40 
    -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions 
    -XX:G1SummarizeRSetStatsPeriod=1 
    -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
    -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9010 
    -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false 
    -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=true
    -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file=/x 
    -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.access.file=/x 
    -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false 
    -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=x
    -Xloggc:/x/bin/logs/gc-%t.log 
    -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=5 -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation
    -XX:GCLogFileSize=20m 
    -XX:+PrintGC 
    -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps 
    -XX:+PrintGCDetails 
    -XX:+PrintHeapAtGC
    -XX:+PrintGCCause 
    -XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution 
    -XX:+PrintReferenceGC 
    -XX:+PrintAdaptiveSizePolicy 
    -Dhudson.upstreamCulprits=true 
    -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch 
    -XX:ParallelGCThreads=40 
    -XX:ConcGCThreads=10 
    -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=40 
    -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=100
```

```
2022-06-08T12:12:47.956+0000: 12088.405: [GC pause (G1 Evacuation Pause) (young)
Desired survivor size 335544320 bytes, new threshold 15 (max 15)
 12088.405: [G1Ergonomics (CSet Construction) start choosing CSet, _pending_cards: 2825, predicted base time: 94.28 ms, remaining time: 305.72 ms, target pause time: 400.00 ms]
 12088.405: [G1Ergonomics (CSet Construction) add young regions to CSet, eden: 0 regions, survivors: 0 regions, predicted young region time: 0.00 ms]
 12088.405: [G1Ergonomics (CSet Construction) finish choosing CSet, eden: 0 regions, survivors: 0 regions, old: 0 regions, predicted pause time: 94.28 ms, target pause time: 400.00 ms]
2022-06-08T12:12:48.145+0000: 12088.594: [SoftReference, 0 refs, 0.0058566 secs]2022-06-08T12:12:48.151+0000: 12088.600: [WeakReference, 0 refs, 0.0039690 secs]2022-06-08T12:12:48.155+0000: 12088.604: [FinalReference, 0 refs, 0.0047858 secs]2022-06-08T12:12:48.160+0000: 12088.608: [PhantomReference, 0 refs, 0 refs, 0.0092318 secs]2022-06-08T12:12:48.169+0000: 12088.618: [JNI Weak Reference, 0.0002371 secs], 0.2374287 secs]
   [Parallel Time: 161.9 ms, GC Workers: 40]
      [GC Worker Start (ms): Min: 12088405.2, Avg: 12088406.5, Max: 12088407.5, Diff: 2.3]
      [Ext Root Scanning (ms): Min: 1.3, Avg: 7.3, Max: 157.4, Diff: 156.1, Sum: 293.4]
      [Update RS (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 0.3, Max: 1.1, Diff: 1.1, Sum: 13.8]
         [Processed Buffers: Min: 0, Avg: 0.4, Max: 1, Diff: 1, Sum: 15]
      [Scan RS (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 0.0, Max: 0.0, Diff: 0.0, Sum: 0.0]
      [Code Root Scanning (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 0.0, Max: 0.0, Diff: 0.0, Sum: 0.0]
      [Object Copy (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 0.1, Max: 0.4, Diff: 0.4, Sum: 5.1]
      [Termination (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 150.8, Max: 156.1, Diff: 156.1, Sum: 6032.5]
         [Termination Attempts: Min: 1, Avg: 1.0, Max: 1, Diff: 0, Sum: 40]
      [GC Worker Other (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 0.0, Max: 0.1, Diff: 0.1, Sum: 1.5]
      [GC Worker Total (ms): Min: 157.6, Avg: 158.7, Max: 160.4, Diff: 2.8, Sum: 6347.1]
      [GC Worker End (ms): Min: 12088565.1, Avg: 12088565.1, Max: 12088565.6, Diff: 0.5]
   [Code Root Fixup: 0.2 ms]
   [Code Root Purge: 0.0 ms]
   [String Dedup Fixup: 17.4 ms, GC Workers: 40]
      [Queue Fixup (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 0.0, Max: 0.0, Diff: 0.0, Sum: 0.0]
      [Table Fixup (ms): Min: 11.5, Avg: 15.0, Max: 16.1, Diff: 4.6, Sum: 599.7]
   [Clear CT: 2.4 ms]
   [Other: 55.5 ms]
      [Choose CSet: 0.0 ms]
      [Ref Proc: 50.7 ms]
      [Ref Enq: 1.6 ms]
      [Redirty Cards: 1.9 ms]
      [Humongous Register: 0.1 ms]
      [Humongous Reclaim: 0.0 ms]
      [Free CSet: 0.0 ms]
   [Eden: 0.0B(4896.0M)->0.0B(4896.0M) Survivors: 0.0B->0.0B Heap: 31.8G(32.0G)->31.8G(32.0G)]
Heap after GC invocations=5587 (full 5):
 garbage-first heap   total 33554432K, used 33310317K [0x00007f8bd0000000, 0x00007f8bd2002000, 0x00007f93d0000000)
  region size 32768K, 0 young (0K), 0 survivors (0K)
 Metaspace       used 812097K, capacity 885950K, committed 886932K, reserved 888832K
}
 [Times: user=7.91 sys=0.00, real=0.24 secs] 
2022-06-08T12:12:48.195+0000: 12088.644: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.2472791 seconds, Stopping threads took: 0.0012268 seconds
 12088.653: [G1Ergonomics (Heap Sizing) attempt heap expansion, reason: allocation request failed, allocation request: 88 bytes]
 12088.653: [G1Ergonomics (Heap Sizing) expand the heap, requested expansion amount: 33554432 bytes, attempted expansion amount: 33554432 bytes]
 12088.653: [G1Ergonomics (Heap Sizing) did not expand the heap, reason: heap already fully expanded]
{Heap before GC invocations=5587 (full 5):
 garbage-first heap   total 33554432K, used 33310317K [0x00007f8bd0000000, 0x00007f8bd2002000, 0x00007f93d0000000)
  region size 32768K, 0 young (0K), 0 survivors (0K)
 Metaspace       used 812097K, capacity 885950K, committed 886932K, reserved 888832K
2022-06-08T12:12:48.205+0000: 12088.653: [Full GC (Allocation Failure) 2022-06-08T12:13:00.000+0000: 12100.448: [SoftReference, 559680 refs, 0.3597706 secs]2022-06-08T12:13:00.360+0000: 12100.808: [WeakReference, 1972081 refs, 0.5324321 secs]2022-06-08T12:13:00.892+0000: 12101.341: [FinalReference, 2421 refs, 0.0027633 secs]2022-06-08T12:13:00.895+0000: 12101.344: [PhantomReference, 53 refs, 1210 refs, 0.0003111 secs]2022-06-08T12:13:00.895+0000: 12101.344: [JNI Weak Reference, 0.0003141 secs] 31G->11G(32G), 31.3282147 secs]
   [Eden: 0.0B(4896.0M)->0.0B(6528.0M) Survivors: 0.0B->0.0B Heap: 31.8G(32.0G)->11.0G(32.0G)], [Metaspace: 812097K->791892K(888832K)]
Heap after GC invocations=5588 (full 6):
 garbage-first heap   total 33554432K, used 11551929K [0x00007f8bd0000000, 0x00007f8bd2002000, 0x00007f93d0000000)
  region size 32768K, 0 young (0K), 0 survivors (0K)
 Metaspace       used 791892K, capacity 849105K, committed 886932K, reserved 888832K
}
```

On the last section, showing up **[Allocation Failure]** which was under first comment.
Obviously still keep testing and tuning that up, that just few Allocation Failures happens over the day. `To sum up, currently see time-to-time Humongous Allocation and around 10 Allocation Failures`.
By saying that, I work out below :

```
-XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=400 
-XX:G1HeapRegionSize=32M
-XX:GCTimeRatio=4
-XX:G1NewSizePercent=15
-XX:G1MaxNewSizePercent=20
-XX:G1ReservePercent=20
-XX:G1MixedGCLiveThresholdPercent=65
-XX:G1HeapWastePercent=10
-XX:G1MixedGCCountTarget=8
-XX:G1OldCSetRegionThresholdPercent=10
-XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=30
```

Comment: I don’t see an `[Allocation Failure]` in your log. Besides that, you did not mention performance, latency (pause times), or memory consumption a single time. So it seems, there is no actual problem and your tuning is just an end in itself.

Comment: @Holger added up **Allocation Failure** evidence. By saying that, block code was leading to this situation. Perhaps, was not enough transparent with data. Anyway, updated last section, also what work out in the meantime.